# Multiples assets into one bundle using Flask-Assets

Tags: flask, sass, flask-assets

I have couples of CSS files in static directory of my Flask project and couple of SCSS fiels. Now I am compiling SCSS files manualy but I want Flask-Assets do it for me. I know how to prepare bundle of CSS only but is there way to mix into this bundle SCSS filec which must be compiled by `filter="pyscss"` before bundling?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the `pyscss` filter but yes, you can bundle CSS and SCSS files together with the `scss` filter. The filter will only apply to the relevant files (`*.scss` in this case.) Working code from one of my projects:

```
assets.register(
    'css_admin',
    Bundle(
        'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'admin.scss',
        filters='scss', output='admin.css'
    )
)
```